# How to loop through and echo value number on rows within the ACF repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to print the count of how many rows are in the ACF repeater row. I have a foreach loop setup but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_section') ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while( have_rows('repeater_section') ): the_row(); ?>
            <li>
                $items = get_field('items', 'option');
                <?php
                    foreach ($items as item) {
                        if (i=0; i<=items.length)
                ?>
                        <p>Items: <?php $i;?></p>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Example output if there are 3 rows of data in the ACF fields.

```
Items: 1
Items: 2
Items: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_section') ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while( have_rows('repeater_section') ): the_row(); ?>
            <li>
                <?php
                    $items = get_field('items', 'option');
                    foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
                        ?>
                        <p>Items: <?php echo $i + 1;?></p>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note, if the key of array is not number, you need to change the code like:

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_section') ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while( have_rows('repeater_section') ): the_row(); ?>
            <li>
                <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    $items = get_field('items', 'option');
                    foreach ($items as $item) {
                        ?>
                        <p>Items: <?php echo $i ++;?></p>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```